# Mapping routes to controller programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to map a route to a controller programmatically? In other words, I want to create a route without a controller, and based on the values of the rest of the parameters in the url map the correct controller to the request?

An example:

url: example.com/about-us

I want to look-up in our system which controller "about-us" is using and then set the controller for the request. It can't be a default controller since there will be many different pages like the one above, that uses different controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need this? Normal MVC way for handling such situations is to add different routes for different controllers, specifying values of parameters inside routes themselves or using `RouteConstraint`s.

Another approach (if you **really** inist on doing routing logic yourself) might be creating a "Routing controller" with, say, a single action which processes all the queries. Inisde this action code you may check for parameter values and do `return RedirectToAction(...)` to redirect request to any action on any controller you need.

**UPDATE:** Example code

In Global.asax.cs create the following default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{*pathInfo}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Route", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

Also add a controller class RouteController.cs with the following content:

```
// usings here...

namespace YourApp.Controllers
{
    public class RouteController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string pathInfo)
        {
            ...
            // programmatically parse pathInfo and determine 
            // controllerName, actionName and routeValues 
            // you want to use to reroute current request
            ...

            return RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the normal way of doing it, but we have customers who only want the url-friendly page name after the domain.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example for second way then

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using custom IRouteHandler implementation. You can restrict route matching with constraints and then rewrite a controller to be instantiated within IRouteHandler implementation.
E.g.

```
    public class RewriteController : IRouteHandler
{

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
                    // here some logic to determine controller name you would like
                    // to instantiate
                    var controllerName = ...;

                    requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controllerName;
        return new HttpControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
    }
}
```

Then your route may be like the following:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute
        (
            name: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
                        defaults: new { action = "Index" },
            constraints: new
            {
                controller = "about-us"
            }
        ).RouteHandler = new RewriteController();
```